# jQuery Mobile - listview data-inset on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
          href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
       $("#local").live('pageinit', function(evt) {
           //$(document).ready(function(){
           var edit = $('#edit');
           edit.append('<li>test1</li>');
           edit.listview('refresh');
       });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

 <div data-role="page" id="index">
   <div data-role="content">
     <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
       <li>
         <a href="#local">
           <h3 class="ui-li-heading">Local Storage Test</h3>
           <p class="ui-li-desc">Just a test</p>
         </a>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </div> 
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="local">
   <div data-role="content">
     <ul id="edit" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
       <li>ntry already there. Append works...</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So my problem is on the second page. I just added a new element and update the list view just to load the css jqm.
But if I use everything that is good pageInit except round the corners of the list view (data frame = "true"). He did not appear rounded, but I checked the css load, and should be all year. But when used document.ready everything is fine. Round the corners of the list view!
Please help me because I do not want to use document.ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $("#local").live('pagecreate', function (evt) { 
   var edit = $('#edit');
   edit.append($('<li>test1</li>')) 
 });
```

Try replacing above code peace